# WPF app dose not display anything after loading the main form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a most concise WPF program. The XAML interface is as follows. The code does not contain any other non automatically generated conten
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoBzL.png)

He runs normally on my own computer, and the interface is as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y69us.png)

But when I start this program on the client's computer, nothing is displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/or2Fq.jpg)

I use .NET Fremwork 4.8. The target platform uses x64. In order to prevent the problem of .NET, I use the same .Net framework generates a WinForms application. Its behavior and display are normal on the client computer, so I suspect this is a WPF problem

Do you have any similar problems and solutions
This is all the code
MainWindow.xaml

```html
<Window x:Class="NET48TEST.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NET48TEST"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="此电脑可以运行有.NET 4.8框架开发的应用程序"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace NET48TEST
{
    /// <summary>
    /// MainWindow.xaml 的交互逻辑
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the actual text inline instead of screenshots of the code, it's a lot easier to work with.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: See this MS docs page for [WPF Globalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/wpf-globalization-and-localization-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), that may likely be the reason that your non-English characters are not displayed in client computer.

Comment: I'm sorry I gave you a bad experience. I have added the specific code to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try：

RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;

Answer (score -1):

How are you running the client, release or debug mode?

try putting a background to the label and centralized

Comment: I just used the WPF application template of VS to create a default program. The configuration is debug, the platform is any CPU, and the target platform generated by the project is x64. Other default configurations are not modified

Comment: I tried to set the background color of the Jiang label to red. The phenomenon is the same as before. The red label is displayed on my computer and a blank is displayed on the customer's computer

Comment: Send the source if you can to review it

Comment: A question. Compile the project before going to production? because if you're just running it it doesn't have the same behavior. If you don't compile, you don't save the changes.